# Passing webforms inputs to class that isn't codebehind asp.net vb

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have some data on a webform that I don't want to write to variables in the codebehind, I want it to pick up the fields in a separate class within the `App_Code`. I've tried `Request.form` and using a Post on the webform but it can't find the method for `Request.form` possibly because it isn't linked.  Currently the below code is pulling in the data from the codebehind but I'm having trouble running functions in a separate class as I am unable to call the data from the codebehind without passing through variables to the function. Is this even possible can you create the form as an object?

```
Public Sub DeclareInputFields()
    input1.CalcReference = inCalcRef.text
    input1.DOL = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(indol.text), Nothing,    DateTime.Parse(indol.text))
    input1.APP = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inAPP.text), Nothing, Decimal.Parse(inAPP.text))
    input1.CPD = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inCPD.text), Nothing, Decimal.Parse(inCPD.text))
End Sub
```

Comment: I've read your question four times, and I'm still not sure what you're trying to ask. What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: @DavidW I'm just trying to access the text entered on a webform in another class outside of the codebehind.

Comment: Can you not just pass the relevant fields (or the Request object itself) as parameter(s) to a function in the App_Code class of interest?

Comment: I could do but I've got quite a few input boxes on the form and doesn't feel like the most efficient way of sending them over.  I'd much prefer to access the text boxes in an object somehow.

Comment: Then simply define the method of the relevant class in your App_Code file to accept a Request object as a single parameter. You can then access the Request.Form collection directly from that method.

Comment: Alternatively, you could define a NameValueCollection parameter in your method and pass Request.Form to it, but that boils down to a slight bit of syntactic sugar either way.

Comment: Think I'll try the request object first and see if that works.  Thanks.

Comment: Surely. I'll post a shell sample so you can see where I'm heading :)

Answer (score 0):

A class defined in a file in App_Code still has to be called from somewhere.  You can instantiate the class in your code behind or use one of the other types of files in ASP.NET.

The request has to go somewhere.  Some other options to look at

An ashx file if your call is something like an AJAX call from JavaScript.

A handler, if you want to do something with the form in addition to the handling of the request.  Look at IHttpModule (which you will also need to register in web.config to do additional handling).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "shell" of how a VB class in App_Code might define functions to take the Form collection, the Request object, or the Controls collection:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Public Class VBDemoClass

   Sub DemoMethod(MyCollection As NameValueCollection)
      ' Do stuff here
   End Sub

   Sub DemoMethod(MyRequest As HttpRequest)
      ' Do stuff here
   End Sub

   Sub DemoMethod(MyControls As ControlCollection)
      ' Do stuff here
   End Sub
End Class
```

In your codebehind, just instantiate the VBDemoClass, then call one of the functions as desired...you could also skip the instantiation if you made the methods static, but that's an implementation detail I'll leave to your purposes.

In your web page codebehind, instantiate your class and call your method with one of the objects already available to you as the codebehind fires:

```
Public Class Page1

    Sub Page_load(ByVal Object as Sender, ByVal e as EventArgs)
       Dim foo as New VBDemoClass
       Foo.DemoMethod(Request.Form)
       ' or
       Foo.DemoMethod(Request)
       ' or
       Foo.DemoMethod(Page.ControlsCollection)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Yep think we're on the same page for sure, am I able to instantiate the whole form or do I need to send each of the inputbox's to the above request?

Comment: You shouldn't need to instantiate the form nor send each item. From your codebehind page, you can invoke the method and pass the Request.Form, Request, or Page.ControlsCollection to these methods (respectively). You already have these objects in hand when the codebehind fires.

Comment: So do I create an instance of the vbdemo class as an object in the codebehind and the call the demo method and pass in the form name as the http request for example? Or can i call the form request from the vbdemo class directly. Apologises if I'm not quite getting it. Many thanks.

Comment: Not a problem! From your codebehind, just instantiate the class, and call the method with the "Request" object, the Form property of the Request object, or the Page.ControlsCollection. You have those in hand when the codebehind fires; you can access them directly from, for example, the Page_Load event. I'll modify my answer to show an example.

Comment: That's perfect now I get it a thanks again really helpful

Comment: My pleasure! Glad to help.